# Will undetected creeptumors take damage

Tags: starcraft-2

Will undetected creep tumors in StarCraft 2 take damage from splash damage?
Such as Hellion, Hellbat or Siegetank splash damage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they will. Cloaked dark templars do take damage if you shoot your own units with a siege tank, so anything cloaked should take damage from splash, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Cloaked units do for sure. But creeptumors are not cloaked by ability like a Dark Templar or a Ghost.

Comment: They are naturally cloaked, and can be directly attacked with vision. I think they are treated the same way as any other cloaked unit :T

Comment: Still it has no cloak ability "passive" or "active" so by mechanic is not the same as the Dark Templar. But would love to see some facts.

Comment: Same thing with widow mines: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxZtKCYA9ak&feature=youtu.be&t=6m20s

Comment: ? Why is this down voted? It's a well worded and a straight question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they do.

Many pro Terran players will place a hellion over the creep tumor they see starting and use other hellions to attack it and kill the creep tumor.

I've seen it done in many pro games in the GSL, I just trying to find a publicly available video now.

The best I can find so far is this thread with screenshots show it is possible with hellions. http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=174308

Comment: yes, TLO used to do it too when he was trying to switch to Terran. It's the same for any invisible unit. A widow mine can get killed by an exploding baneling, A widow mine can damage a dark templar by shooting a zealot next to it, etc.